# Insert Data from row 1 in oracle database table in grails

Tags: oracle, grails, grails-2.0

I don't know that is this a silly question or not but I need to solve this. I have search with goggle but no result to satisfy me. The question is > I am inserting some value into a table. I am using oracle as database and grails 2.1.1. when it is inserting value in the table the row id does not begin with 1 but I need to start that particular table to start with 1. Cause There will be only four row in that table and I need to insert them by the id like 1,2,3,4 so that i can get them in various part of application. But it is giving other id and after then I changed them to 1,2,3,4. Is there any way to do this in domain level in grails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an oracle sequence.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
MINVALUE value
MAXVALUE value
START WITH value
INCREMENT BY value
CACHE value;

CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 4
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 1;
```

Then in the domain specify the sequence

```
class MyDomain {
   ...

   static mapping = {
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'my_seq']
   }
}
```

**EDITED:**

If you are using liquibase migration then use add a new changeset and then add it to you changelog.groovy.

To create a sequence add a changeSet into your grails-app/migrations

sequence.groovy

```
changeSet(author: "me", id: "add-sequence") {
    createSequence(sequenceName: "my_seq")
}
```

changelog.groovy

```
include file: 'sequence.groovy'
```

For more options on creating sequences using liquibase look here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_sequence.html

Comment: where should I make this sequence in my app and how to get this sequence ?!!

Comment: You will have to create sequence in your oracle database. Are you using grails liquibase plugin for migration? Or How are you migrating / creating tables?

Comment: database-migration-1.1

Comment: @SumonBappi Edited my post and added more info.

Comment: it's working but if i drop the table then it is giving error to execute the app

Comment: @SumonBappi If you drop the table then you should also drop the associated sequence and re-create when you create the table again. How are you dropping the table?

Comment: it is working for me only with this line in mapping section in domain >> " id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'procurementType_sequence'] "

Answer (score 0):

instead of this create your own id field in table and use sequences to generate any id you like, for example : `create sequence id_seq start with 1 increment by 1` and use it while inserting : `insert int TABLE_NAME values (id_seq.nextval, ...);`. I would recommend you not to depend on oracle's row_id, because it's controlled by db and is genereted for it's needs (see also [oracle ref](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm)).